# JAVA MappedByteBuffer where is the high efficiency?

Tags: java, io

I try to use java to write a data management tool.
I need to use an efficient random file to read and write.
I try to use the friend recommended file mapping.
But the effect doesn't seem to be good.
I use RandomAccessFile to read and write files at a speed that is 10 times as fast as MappedByteBuffer.

```
File file = new File("D:\\testdb");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
RandomAccessFile accessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
accessFile.setLength(65536);
FileChannel fileChannel = accessFile.getChannel();
Random random = new Random(0);
{
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        byte[] data = new byte[4096];
        accessFile.seek(4096);
        accessFile.read(data, 0, 4096);
        accessFile.seek(4096);
        accessFile.write(data);
    }
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - time);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
{
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = fileChannel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 12288, 4096);
        buffer.force();
    }
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - time);
}
```

I would like to know where the advantages of MappedByteBuffer?

I added data to read and write. The time spent is even more obvious.

```
    {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
            byte[] data = new byte[4096];
            accessFile.seek(4096);
            accessFile.read(data, 0, 4096);

            for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                data[j] = data[data.length - j - 1];
            }

            accessFile.seek(4096);
            accessFile.write(data);
        }
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - time);
    }
    {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
            MappedByteBuffer buffer = fileChannel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 12288, 4096);

            for (int j = 0; j < buffer.capacity(); j++) {
                buffer.put(j, buffer.get(buffer.capacity() - j - 1));
            }

            buffer.force();
        }
        System.out.println(System.nanoTime() - time);
    }

Output：
    39655738
    11786737561
```

I try to do data management, here is the cache.
Has been loaded into the memory of the data do not need to care about.
Because the data must be read or written.
Must be synchronized with the file after the end.
If these data are not modified.
Do not need synchronization.
This will further save time. RandomAccessFile's advantage will be more obvious

Comment: You could use JMH for micro benchmarking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing applies and oranges.

You are comparing the time to seek and read data via a `RandomAccessFile` with the time to *create a mapping* via `MappedByteBuffer`. Creating the mapping does a lot of things behind the scenes but it doesn't do any I/O.

What you should be testing is getting the data from bytes 4097-8192, and rewriting it, 1024 times. Not creating the mapping 1024 times. Nobody in their right mind is going to do that.

Your test doesn't make sense.

Comment: The rewriting speed of the array must be faster than the buffer.
I've been doing experiments about reading and writing very early.
RandomAccessFile read and write a 4KB time is far less than MappedByteBuffer.
Even if the change is written again, the RandomAccessFile will be much shorter.

Comment: None of that is reflected in your question. I am commenting on the code you posted. We can't read your mind. The generally accepted speed up for `MappedByteBuffers` in read-only mode is 20%, and in write mode zero.